# How to insert a button using Java Based Program in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, button

I just want to ask how to create a button using java based program. I want to have a button on my official game like Next button that if the user clicked it, it will allow them to go to the next level of the game. It's like a pause/resume/stop/restart button inside the game.

This is the code of the Game I used. I can't see the declaration of button here but when I played this, it has a exit button(?) above that allows the user to go back to previous form.

```
public class NewGame extends Activity {
static MediaPlayer mp1;
MediaPlayer jump;
MediaPlayer takecoin;
GameLoopThread gameLoopThread;


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // for no title
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(new GameView(this));
}

public class GameView extends SurfaceView {
    Bitmap bmp;
    Bitmap background, taya, note1;
    Bitmap run1;
    Bitmap run6;
    Bitmap jump2;
    Bitmap coin;
    Bitmap exit;

    // MediaPlayer mp1,jump,takecoin;
    private SurfaceHolder holder;
    // private gameloop gameLoopThread;
    private int x = 0, y = 0, z = 0, delay = 0, getx, gety, sound = 1;
    int show = 0, sx, sy = 0;
    int cspeed = 0, kspeed = 0, gameover = 0;
    int score = 0, health = 120, reset = 0;
    private int min = 1, sec = 0;
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private Runnable mRunnable;
    private boolean isStop = false;
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")


    public GameView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(sec <= 0){
                    if(min > 0){
                        sec = 59;
                        min--;
                        isStop = false;
                    }
                    else{
                        //stop timer here
                        Log.e("TIMER", "timer stop!");
                        mHandler.removeCallbacks(this);
                        isStop = true;
                    }
                }
                else{
                    sec--;
                    isStop = false;
                }

                Log.i("TIMER", "min: " + min + " sec: " + sec);
                if(!isStop){
                    mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);

                }
            }
        }, 1000);


        gameLoopThread = new GameLoopThread(this);
        holder = getHolder();

        holder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                // for stoping the game
                gameLoopThread.setRunning(false);
                gameLoopThread.getThreadGroup().interrupt();
            }

            @SuppressLint("WrongCall")
            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                gameLoopThread.setRunning(true);
                gameLoopThread.start();

            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format,
                    int width, int height) {
            }
        });

        // getting the screen size
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

        sx = display.getWidth();
        sy = display.getHeight();
        ;
        cspeed = x / 4;
        kspeed = x / 4;
        background = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.imgluneta);
        run1 = BitmapFactory
                .decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.run1);
        run6 = BitmapFactory
                .decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.run6);
        jump2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.run11);
        coin = BitmapFactory
                .decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.coin);
        exit = BitmapFactory
                .decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.exit);
        taya = BitmapFactory
                .decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.taya);
        note1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.note1);

        exit = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(exit, 25, 25, true);

        background = Bitmap
                .createScaledBitmap(background, 2 * sx, sy, true);
        // health dec
        note1 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(note1, sx, sy, true);

        mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(NewGame.this, R.raw.game);
        jump = MediaPlayer.create(NewGame.this, R.raw.jump);
        takecoin = MediaPlayer.create(NewGame.this, R.raw.cointake);
    }

    // on touch method

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            show = 1;

            getx = (int) event.getX();
            gety = (int) event.getY();
            // exit
            if (getx < 25 && gety < 25) {
                System.exit(0);

            }
            // sound off
            if (getx > 25 && getx < 60) {
                if (gety < 25) {
                    sound = 0;
                    mp1.stop();
                }
            }
            // sound on
            if (getx > 61 && getx < 90) {
                if (gety < 25) {
                    sound = 1;

                }
            }
            // restart game
            if (getx > 91 && gety < 25) {
                if (health <= 0) {
                    gameLoopThread.setPause(0);
                    health = 100;
                    score = 0;

                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    @SuppressLint("WrongCall")
    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);

        // background moving
        z = z - 10;
        if (z == -sx) {
            z = 0;
            canvas.drawBitmap(background, z, 0, null);

        } else {
            canvas.drawBitmap(background, z, 0, null);
        }

        // running player

        x += 5;
        if (x == 20) {
            x = 5;
        }

        if (show == 0) {
            if (x % 2 == 0) {
                int height = run1.getHeight();
                canvas.drawBitmap(run1, sx / 16, (15 * sy / 18) - height / 2, null);
                // kinfe hit
                if (kspeed == 20) {
                    kspeed = sx;
                    health -= 25;
                    canvas.drawBitmap(note1, 0, 0, null);
                }
            } else {
                int height = run6.getHeight();
                canvas.drawBitmap(run6, sx / 16, (15 * sy / 18) - height / 2, null);
                // kinfe hit
                if (kspeed == 20) {
                    kspeed = sx / 2;
                    health -= 25;
                    canvas.drawBitmap(note1, 0, 0, null);
                }
            }
        }

        // for jump
        if (show == 1) {
            if (sound == 1) {
                jump.start();
            }
            int height=jump2.getHeight();
            canvas.drawBitmap(jump2, sx / 16, (3 * sy / 4)-height, null);
            // score
            if (cspeed <= (sx / 8)-height/2 && cspeed >= (sx / 16)-height/2) {
                if (sound == 1) {
                    takecoin.start();

                }
                cspeed = sx / 2;
                score += 10;
            }

            // jump-hold
            delay += 1;
            if (delay == 3) {
                show = 0;
                delay = 0;
            }
        }

        // for coins
        cspeed = cspeed - 5;
        if (cspeed == -sx / 2) {
            cspeed = sx / 2;
            canvas.drawBitmap(coin, cspeed, 3 * sy / 4, null);
        } else {
            canvas.drawBitmap(coin, cspeed, 3 * sy / 4, null);
        }

        // kinfe
        kspeed = kspeed - 20;
        int height = taya.getHeight();
        canvas.drawBitmap(taya, kspeed, (15 * sy / 18) - height / 2, null);
        if (kspeed < 0) {
            kspeed = sx;
            health -= 25;   
        } 

        // score
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setFakeBoldText(true);
        paint.setTextSize(15);
        paint.setTextAlign(Align.LEFT);
        canvas.drawText("Score :" + score, 3 * sx / 4, 20, paint);
        // exit
        canvas.drawBitmap(exit, 0, 0, null);
        if (sound == 1) {
            mp1.start();
            mp1.setLooping(true);
        }

        // health
        Paint myPaint = new Paint();
        myPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        myPaint.setStrokeWidth(10);
        canvas.drawText("Health :" + health, 0, (sy / 8) - 5, myPaint);
        canvas.drawRect(0, sy / 8, health, sy / 8 + 10, myPaint);

        // game over
        if (health <= 0) {
            gameover = 1;
            mp1.stop();
            canvas.drawText("GAMEOVER OVER", sx / 2, sy / 2, myPaint);
            canvas.drawText("YOUR SCORE : " + score, sx / 2, sy / 4,
                    myPaint);
            canvas.drawText("Restart", 91, 25, myPaint);
            gameLoopThread.setPause(1);
        }
        // restart

        if (reset == 1) {
            gameLoopThread.setPause(0);
            health = 100;
            score = 0;
        }

        // timer
                    Paint mypaint = new Paint();
                    myPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
                    myPaint.setStrokeWidth(10);
                    mypaint.setTextSize(50);
                    canvas.drawText("Timer :" + min + sec,min, sec, mypaint);
    }


}

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    NewGame.mp1.isPlaying();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    NewGame.mp1.pause();
    }   



   }
```

Comment: Did you try any code , any efforts from your side?

Comment: @Ann Lee, your question is too general. Basically, add a Button widget to your layout and assign an onClick listener to it.

Comment: No. I have added button using findviewbyid but it don't show the button once I've played the game.

Comment: Can you post your xml layout file?

Comment: sadly, the xml of the game is blank. I've used java based. Pure java.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a button in Java code-

```
Button button = new Button(this);
```

where 'this' is context.

Comment: I've added the code of the game. Please take a look at it.